# Laravel Delete/Forget Cookie not working

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.3

How do you a delete cookies in Laravel. This is not working:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{

    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('cavpad'));
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('cavuser'));

    return redirect('/');
```

}

This works, but seems the wrong way to do it:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cavpad', '', 0, null, env('APP_DOMAIN')));
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cavuser', '', 0, null, env('APP_DOMAIN')));
```

Why does the first way not work, but the second way does... btw, has nothing to do with the env()... Just added that in there...

Comment: It should be `Cookie::forget()` inside `Cookie::queue()`

Comment: What is your cookie driver?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the code I provided, it's pretty much the same, but I know that this way of doing it works for me. But if you need to do it inline, this might also work for you:

```
Cookie::queue(
    Cookie::forget('cookieName')
);
```

This is how I think it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting like this:

```
return redirect('/')->withCookie(Cookie::forget('cavpad'))->withCookie(Cookie::forget('cavuser'));
```