# Laravel: Cookie::forget() not working

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm having an issue with deleting cookies in Laravel 5.6. I've tried various different things based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941672/cookieforget-not-working-laravel-5-1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063240/laravel-cookieforget-doesnt-work), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840080/laravel-delete-forget-cookie-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575041/destroy-all-cookie-in-laravel-not-working) question, but none of them work;

1.

```
return response()
    ->redirectToRoute('home')
    ->withCookie(Cookie::forget('code'))
    ->withCookie(Cookie::forget('email'));
```

2.

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('code'));
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('email'));

return redirect('/');
```

3.

```
Cookie::queue('code', null, -1);
Cookie::queue('email', null, -1);

return redirect('/');
```

4.

```
return redirect('/')
    ->withCookie(cookie('code', '', -1))
    ->withCookie(cookie('email', '', -1));
```

5.

```
return response()
    ->redirectToRoute('home')
    ->withCookie(cookie('code', '', -1))
    ->withCookie(cookie('email', '', -1));
```

3, 4 and 5 don't even change the value of the cookie, the original value still remains in the cookies. I don't know what other methods I could try, so any help would be appreciated.

Cookies are generally added like this in Laravel:

```
return response()
    ->redirectToRoute($this->handleRedirect($result))
    ->cookie('code', $request->code, $this->duration, null, $this->domain)
    ->cookie('email', $request->email, $this->duration, null, $this->domain);
```

Comment: Do you have the `\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class` middleware enabled on your route?

Comment: It's enabled in the `$middlewareGroups` array, this means it's used on all web routes by default, right?

Comment: for the web routes yes. You can check if it's ok with `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Yeah the `web` middelware group is enabled on all routes, so that's not the problem.

Comment: How these cookies were added in the first place? By Laravel? JS? Are you able to add another one?

Comment: I edited the OP to include how I add cookies, might be easier to read than as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up switching to sessions instead of cookies as this was easier to work with according to someone I asked. I now use `Session::flush()` and `Session::forget('key')` to remove the necessary data.

Answer (score 2):

I remember that I had some issues with laravel cookies, and finally I decided to set cookies manually with PHP's native function,

to set a new cookie use this code :

```
setcookie('index', 'value', time() + $secondsToRemember, '/');
```

and for deleting them use this code :

```
setcookie('index', 'Expired', time() - 100000, '/');
```

this is the easiest way of handling cookies.

and after that code you can return back or redirect user or do something else

you can read this page for more detailed explanation :
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp